# How to run a shell script from inside Mathematica

Tags: external-calls

I have a very basic question. I have a shell file test.sh that prints let's say `Yeah` to a file called `output.txt`:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Yeah" > output.txt
```

I am running the `Run` command from the notebook:

```
Run["sh test.sh"]
```

But it is not creating the file `output.txt`. Can anyone tell me please what is going wrong?

Comment: It works for me, are you looking in the right directory?  When I run it `Run["sh test.sh"]` I get an output 0, and the `output.txt` shows up in the same directory.

Comment: Thank you Jason but it is a little strange. I am getting an output 0 only when I specify the entire path to test.sh (though both the notebook and test.sh are in the same directory). But even then I do not see output.txt in the same directory. So Run["sh /Users/sxm016/Documents/Alignment/Alignment_ras_sos/March_\
2016_ras_Gauss_multivariate/Bistable_traj/test.sh"] gives me an output 0 but no file named output.txt in the same directory

Comment: That is strange.  What is the output from `Directory[]`?  Perhaps the `output.txt` file is going somewhere in Mathematica's path?

Comment: Thank you so much. That is exactly what is happening. When I typed Directory[] it showed me the path to my home not the current directory. Thank you. Can you please tell me how to change the mathematica path ?

Comment: you want `SetDirectory[]`.  I actually have a line in my `/home/jason/.Mathematica/Kernel/init.m` file to say `SetDirectory["~/Documents/Mathematica"];` so that I always start in that directory

Comment: Thank you Jason. I really appreciate your help. It works now

Comment: @JasonB, Please repost your comment as an answer, so the Q/A makes sense and can be referenced.

Answer (score 12):

The issue here is that when *Mathematica* executes an external system command, at least on Linux, it does so from the current directory.  You can verify this via

```
Directory[]
Run["! echo $PWD > file.txt"];
FilePrint["file.txt"]
```

[image]

which is my default working directory.  I actually have a line in my

`/home/jason/.Mathematica/Kernel/init.m`

file that says `SetDirectory["~/Documents/Mathematica"];` so that I always start in that directory.

Comment: Well done, thank you!

Comment: @Louis Absolutely, it's always an open question what to do when a question is answered in the comments but it doesn't get closed.

Comment: Yeah, I did that and it works. Thanks Jason. You saved me time

Comment: @Sayak - Glad to help.  If that answers the question you could mark it as solved, then it won't be in the list of unanswered questions.