# Running an external simulation program from Mathematica

Tags: scripting, external-calls, unix

I have a physics simulation program which I run through a terminal window (I use a Mac) as shown below:

```
user$ programName inputfile.ele
```

I would like run a `*.sh` script that runs the simulation from Mathematica. I tried using `Run` but had no luck, though I was able to successfully follow through this example ([How to run a shell script from inside Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109435/how-to-run-a-shell-script-from-inside-mathematica)).

I am looking for advice on how to go about running the simulation from Mathematica. Ultimately, I would like to create a Do-loop and have Mathematica run the following script with different t2 values:

```
Do[
   Clear[t2]
   t2 = i;
   t2scan = Table[t2, {71}];
   t3scan = Range[0.01, 0.08, 0.001];
   t2plus3 = t2scan + t3scan;
   ans = 
     Table[
       NSolve[{SimpleEquation1 == 0, SimpleEquation2 == 0.03} /. t3 -> angle, 
       {f, g}], {angle, t3scan}];
   fdrift = Flatten[f /. ans];
   gdrift = Flatten[g /. ans];
   Export["/Users/Desktop/t2.txt", t2scan];
   Export["/Users/t3.txt", t3scan];
   Export["/Users/t2plus3.txt", t2plus3];
   Export["/Users/f.txt", fdrift];
   Export["/Users/g.txt", gdrift];
   Run["sh myScript.sh"]
   , {i, 0.01, 0.08, 0.001}]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you get as a return when you execute the `Run` command, 0 or some other number?

Comment: Yes! I get "32512"

Comment: okay - so that means you get an error message of some kind, it returns 0 when it runs correctly.  Perhaps its a directory issue?  Is the script `myScript.sh` in the same directory that *Mathematica* is running from?  If you type `Directory[]` you see what MMA's working directory is.  If you go to a terminal and cd into that directory and type your `sh` command, does it work from there?

Comment: I dont think its a directory issue; I SetDirectory[] to all the same folder. I figured the simulation runs from any directory because its part of the "PATH" variables. Maybe Mathematica doesn't recognize the simulation as a variable because its variables/environment is set differently than my terminal?

Comment: It's possible - See if adding the full path to the executable changes it...

Comment: Putting the full path for the simulation in my script just changed the number Mathematica spits out to 256.

Comment: It's frustrating that you can't **see** the error message it gets from the terminal.  If you add " > output.txt" to the end of the command does it pit any info in that file?

Comment: Holy moly! It worked! The output.txt told me exactly what was wrong!

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, two things needed to be done and amended in my script:

1. The exact path location of the simulation needed to clarified. So, instead of writing:

   ```
    programName inputfile.ele
   ```

I had to put:

```
     /User/location/somewhere/programName inputfile.ele
```

2. Secondly, by putting a generic output I was able to more clearly see exactly what the problem is:

   ```
    programName inputfile.ele>output.txt
   ```

My particularly issue is that my simulation requires a rpn definition file which is normally set as a path/variable in my terminal but apparently Mathematica does not recognize it. And wallah, after setting the rpn definition file in my script I could run the simulation program easily through Mathematica!